# I am having trouble automating Internet Explorer with Microsoft Excel VBA

Tags: windows, oracle, excel, oracle-apex, vba

I am trying to automate data input into a text field on a website on Internet Explorer 11 with Microsoft Excel VBA and my code is working for every site I have tested it on (Google, Yahoo, etc) except for the one website I need it to work on. The website I need the code to work on is Apex on the front-end and Oracle on the back-end. Strangely, the same code will work for the Apex website when then website is opened on a computer running Windows 7, but not when it is opened on a computer running Windows 10. The problem is that I need the code to work on the computer running Windows 10. When I run the code on a computer running Windows 10 I get the following error:

```
     Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)':

     Automation error
     Unspecified error
```

Could anyone please give me any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim objIE As Object 

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'make IE browser visible
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page 
objIE.navigate "This is where I put the website address"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'in the Apex web page search textbox put "test"
objIE.document.getElementById("P101_USERNAME").Value = "test"

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance that the web page is not fully loading before trying to "input" ? To check it out try this line just after `do while objIE.busy`  which just adds a 5 second wait time. `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))` If you still get the same results, step through the code using F8 to make sure where it's erroring out.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I finally got it to work by creating an instance of InternetExplorerMedium instead of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "medium" thing. I tried it out on one of my scripts, but it didn't work. I did run across this though. `Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` and then `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`. I've been using `Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`. Not sure if there's a difference, they both work about the same. Good luck.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help!!